# Check if a given order is a legal postorder traversal

Tags: traversal, binary-search-tree

If you have a binary search tree with ten nodes, storing integers 0 through 9, how do we decide if a sequence cannot represent a postorder traversal of the tree? I understand that the root has to be the last one in the sequence, but I could not arrive at any pattern. A pseudocode would be great too! (It's not homework, practicing for interviews)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, you know what the root is.  So you know the range of values in each sub tree.  If the sequence, less the root, doesn't split into two sequences, one less than and one greater than the root then it isn't valid.  If it does, you need to recursively check the two sub-traversals.  If everything works, then it is valid.